# Unable To Render Control To Placeholder

Tags: c#, .net, sitecore, sitecore6

The following code will not add a control to an aspx placeholder:

```
var control = new ASCXControl { ID="searchFilters", Filters = filters };

var placeholder = Utility.FindControlRecursive(Page, "rightColumnSearchFilters") as PlaceHolder;
if(placeholder != null){
  placeholder.Controls.Add(control);
  placeholder.Visible = true;
}
```

When debugging, the placeholder is found and the control shows as added to the placeholder controls collection after entering the block, but yet I see nothing render into the placeholder on the page.

I currently need to pass variables to the control in order to find the filters I need to display. Although I don't like passing variables between controls, I don't see any other way.

What am I missing would make the control not render? Is there a better way to do this?

EDIT:

I am trying to get the HTML inside of the ascx to render. I am able to get the Filters parameters inside the Page_Load on the control.

Comment: Is `ASCXControl` a regular user control, or something unique to Sitecore?

Comment: ASCXControl is a regular user control inheriting from `System.Web.UI.UserControl`

Comment: Is rightColumnSearchFilters an asp:Placeholder or an sc:Placeholder?

Comment: @techphoria414, is Ann L's answer the preferred way for Sitecore to programmatically add a sublayout / control to a placeholder or is there another method?

Comment: Really depends on what you're trying to do. Using a sublayout gives you some additional capabilities. In that case, you'd need to use an sc:Placeholder, add Sublayout control to it instead of the user control, and then likely call the Expand method on the placeholder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may or may not be the whole problem, but usually trying to instantiate a `UserControl` the way you're doing it leads to problems.  You should do it using the `LoadControl(path)` method of the `Page` class:

```
ASCXControl ctl = (ASCXControl) LoadControl("path");
```

I'm not 100% sure, but I think that if you just instantiate it like an ordinary class/control, you wind up not running all the event handlers (such as `Load`) that you usually would.